# Question about the nature of a Galois group over 2 successive field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Given finite field extensions $K\subset E \subset F$, let $p\in E[x]$. Given any $\theta\in Gal(F/E)$, I know that $p(\theta(u))=0$ for any root $u$ of $p$ in $E$, i.e., $\theta$ permutes the roots of $p$ in $F$. My questions is:

Given $\theta\in Gal(F/K)$, does $\theta$ again permute the roots of $p$ in $F$?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I am just learning Galois Theory, and this isn't homework, it is just something I can't sort out. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: What can we say if we know that the $\theta(a)\in F\setminus E$ for all $a\in F$?

Comment: The answer is no, since $p$ is not a polynomial with coefficients in $K$.

Comment: The answer depends. You tagged the question *finite-fields* implying here that the sets $K,E,F$ are all finite. In that case the answer is affirmative, because any extension of finite fields is Galois. If the tag was added accidentally (happens often enough - particularly to those askers who do not bother to read the tag description), then it is easy enough to construct counterexamples of situations where both $E/K$ and $F/E$ are Galois, but $F/K$ is not. On the side of groups that corresponds to a situation where $K\unlhd H$, $H\unlhd G$, but $K$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: So please clarify.